# Cannot access rails admin dashboard as admin in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am using custom rails4-starterkit by joe johnston et al., (simple10) and I am unable to access dashboard of Railsadmin. I have gone through many cancan and RailsAdmin tutorials, Since its custom coded I'm confused what to change and how to change. help needed !

```
Platform: Rails 4.1 Ruby 2.1.0 Webrick Redis postgresql 9.1
```

initializers/rails_admin.rb here

http://pastebin.com/2raVSXHP

models/concerns/ability.rb

http://pastebin.com/AUJ7cDxE

models/concerns/user.rb

```
      def reverse_merge_attributes_from_auth(auth)
    auth.oauth_data.each do |k, v|
      self[k] = v if self.respond_to?("#{k}=") && self[k].blank?
    end
  end

  # Do not require email confirmation to login or perform actions
  def confirmation_required?
    false
  end

  def send_welcome_emails
    UserMailer.delay.welcome_email(self.id)
    # UserMailer.delay_for(5.days).find_more_friends_email(self.id)
  end
end
```

Please go through paste bin codes and suggest me workaround/easy solution

Grateful

Comment: What error or behavior are you seeing?

Normally, you just need to create a new user and set user.is_admin = true. Then you should see an "Admin" link in the topnav menu.

Comment: Thanks @simple10 I had to manually set is_admin value as TRUE in phpgadmin (Postgres) !